# Mouse Down events in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouse, nsevent

I know this question has been asked a lot before, but nothing will work for me. The following code will not do anything at all.

```
- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent*)event {
    NSLog(@"It worked!");

}
```

I have tried a lot of different methods to get this to work, including creating custom `NSEvents` in this way:

```
NSEvent *someEvent;

- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent*)someEvent {
    NSLog(@"It worked!");

}
```

This is my .h file:

```
@interface test : NSWindow <NSWindowDelegate> {

}
```

Would somebody explain how to make this do something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure your class inherits from `NSWindow` and conforms to the `<NSWindowDelegate>` protocol.  Otherwise, that's just a method that happens to be named `mouseDown`, and nobody will ever call it.

**Update:**  Change your header file so that it looks like this:

```
@interface test : NSWindow <NSWindowDelegate> {  

}
```

In other words, *don't* put a prototype of `mouseDown` inside the interface definition, or anywhere else in the `.h` file.

In your implementation file (`.m`) put just the method:

```
- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent*)someEvent {         
    NSLog(@"It worked!");          
}
```

Assuming that you have logging turned on in the device (are you sure you can read `NSLog` output from elsewhere in your program?), you should see "It worked!" printed there.

I'm not an obj-C expert by any means, but I think by putting the `mouseDown` prototype inside the interface definition, you were basically creating your own custom `mouseDown` method which hid the "real" one.  This indicated to the compiler that it should *not* call your `mouseDown` method on a window click.

Comment: I have already done that, but it just doesn't work. I'll edit the post to show everything I have done.

Comment: Response to the update. I have already done that (I just forgot to separate the code for the .h and .m files.

Comment: @Justin: are you sure it isn't working? The only effect clicking your window would have would be to write something to the log. Are you sure your app is able to write to the log and that you're able to read the log? What happens if you show an alert dialog instead of writing to the log?

Comment: I don't know how to show an alert. And yes, other things in this program can send NSLogs.

Comment: Another possibility is that you have a view on your window which is intercepting and handling the mouse events (meaning they never reach your window).

Comment: The window does have a view, but I haven't added anything to it. I just created a new Xcode application for Cocoa and went straight into the code.

Comment: @Justin did you actually change the class of the window in your MainMenu.xib from `NSWindow` to `test`?  Simply defining a class is not good enough.  You have to have an actual instantiation of that class (ie, an object) for the methods to work.

Comment: It won't let me change it to "test", so I thought it was fine. EDIT: Thank you! It's working perfectly now!

Comment: @Justin: Dave deserves the credit, but at least we proved this was a real question. :)

Comment: @MusiGenesis yeah, I flagged it for moderator attention asking that it be unlocked and reopened, with this answer as proof that it's a real question.  Perhaps not a very *descriptive* question, but a real question none-the-less.

Comment: @Dave: you learn something new every year, I guess - I thought flagging was just for offensive language/spam/etc.

Answer (score 4):

Your subclass must have a parent class of NSResponder, otherwise you will not get any events.

Comment: What is a subclass? Do you mean that "test" in "@interface test : NSWindow <NSWindowDelegate> {" is a subclass?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that your class is a subclass of NSWindow which is a subclass of NSResponder.

Comment: I didn't even know what a subclass was. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Justin: You should read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it does NOT need to be a subclass of NSWindow. It does need to be a subclass of NSResponder.

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the NSWindow class, you should be overriding the NSView "contentView" of the NSWindow class to capture mouse events. Most of the decorations (NSViews) on the window outside of the contentView are private.

Just create a new NSView that overrides mouseDown, etc and add it as your content view to the NSWindow object.