# Mouse Down events in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouse, nsevent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mouse Down events in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543084/mouse-down-events-in-objective-c)

I know this question has been asked a lot before, but nothing will work for me. The following code will not do anything at all.

This is the first line in my header file:

```
@interface test : NSWindow <NSWindowDelegate> {


- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent*)event {
    NSLog(@"It worked!");

}
```

I have tried a lot of different methods to get this to work, including creating custom `NSEvents` in this way:

```
NSEvent *someEvent;

- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent*)someEvent {
    NSLog(@"It worked!");

}
```

Would somebody please post the code needed to make this do something?